# Services 3: How to retrieve the current logged in user ID

Tags: services

I can get a list of all users by going to //endpoint/user/ but how do I return the current user?

My primary goal is to find out if the user is authenticated.

Comment: you can use global $user;$id = $user->uid;or you ask about other thing also you can use user_is_logged_in() to check if authenticated

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to retrieve this information through web services using the Services module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can use the system resource "connect".  Enable that resource:

- to go admin/structure/services/list/serp/resources
- expand "system"
- check "connect" Hit save

Then, you post (posting nothing) to /system/connect and it returns the current user info and session id.

Comment: I always get the anonymous user, even when using the same browser and logged in. Anything else that needs to be done?